# Screen shaking/flickering randomly after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, 20.04, flicker

As heading decribe, my screen image will "shake" or flicker with random intervals. This started after upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04.

For the most part everything is normal, then, suddenly, my screen picture will either move rapidly to the left, in a shaky motion, or it will blink. It is all over and back to normal in less than half a second. I have a Nvidia GeForce MX130 screencard. Anyone familiar with this issue, and know how to fix it?